# Как связать оружие и персонажа?

Tags: unity3d

Я создаю 2d игру с видом сверху. У меня есть персонаж и много оружия, которое будет выпадать с боссов. Как реализовать привязку оружия к руки персонажа?(Как например в Enter the gungeon). Орудий много, и я считаю правильным решением сделать отдельно анимацию оружия и персонажа. 
Нужно чтобы персонаж и оружие поворачивались за курсором

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: лично я не понимаю в чем конкретно вопрос? `Как нарисовать еще один вариант персонажа с новым оружием?` Так же как рисовал персонажа и со старым оружием. `Как реализовать переключение?` Так заведи себе `enum Weapon`  и создай SelectedWeapon у твоего персонажа да переключай через него...

Comment: Рисовать персонажа с новым оружием это бред, тк придется делать новые анимации для каждого персонажа с одним и тем же предметом

Comment: а, я прочитал буквально "и я считаю правильным решением сделать отдельно анимацИЮ оружия и персонажа."(т.е. на каждое оружие отдельную анимацию персонажа). А ты имел ввиду "и я считаю правильным решением сделать отдельнЫМИ анимациИ оружия и персонажа. "